# Copy Multiple Rows To New Sheet Based On Criteria In Just One Row

Tags: excel, vba

My Dataset is as such: Column A = ID numbers, Column B = Test Type, Column C = Results.

Each ID in Column A appears more than once. For each occurrence, there is a test with the result being either "Yes" or "No".

If one test result for a given ID comes back "Yes", I want to copy all rows for that ID to a new sheet in the same workbook.

So in the photo I've attached: ID 1234, test type Blue came back with "Yes", while test type Pink was "No". I want to copy both rows of ID 1234 to a new sheet because one or more of the tests (Blue or Pink) came back "Yes". ID 4321 should be left untouched because both tests were "No".

I've no idea on how to start this, I'm sure 'If, Then' statements may be involved.

Any suggestions how to tackle this in VBA?

[Sheet with ID, Test Type and Results: an example but there would be about 1000+ rows of data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpUcO.png)

Comment: You say *move them to a new sheet*.  Does that mean *remove them from the original sheet* or just copy them ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Copy to a new sheet, leaving the original behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this ok ?

```
Sub filter_and_copy()

    ' Variables
    Dim oWsFrom As Worksheet
    Dim oWsTo As Worksheet
    Dim oRangeData As Range
    Dim nbRow As Long
    
    ' Settings
    Set oWsFrom = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set oWsTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
    oWsTo.Cells.ClearContents
    Set oRangeData = oWsFrom.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    nbRow = oRangeData.Rows.Count
    
    ' Formula and filter
    With oWsFrom
        .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Formula"
        .Cells(2, 4).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,""yes"")"
        .Cells(2, 4).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(nbRow, 4))
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="1"
    End With
    
    ' Copy
    oWsFrom.Range(Columns(1), Columns(3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy oWsTo.Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Vincent Farcy, this almost worked. It didn't copy over the row if both tests were "Yes" for same ID, 
But this def is better than what I had!

Comment: ;-)  ==>  ````.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=1"````

Comment: Ha! That was easy!  Cheers for that.

Comment: I have a problem with this code when I run it on my actual data- it doesn't seem to recognises the formula, until I hit return key.
' Formula and filter
    With oWsFrom
        .Cells(1, 19).Value = "Formula"
        .Cells(2, 19).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,N:N,""yes"")"
        .Cells(2, 19).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(2, 19), .Cells(nbRow, 19))
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=">=1"
    End With
    
    ' Copy
    oWsFrom.Range(Columns(1), Columns(17)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy oWsTo.Cells(1, 1)
'

Comment: check the format of your cells.it shouldn't be text format.

Comment: No, hasn't helped changing it to General or number. any other ideas?

Comment: menu data >> text to columns on the column with formulas perhaps

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code, which uses `.Calculate` to force the formula to work automatically every time I run the macro. Thanks again for the help

```
 Worksheets("Total").Activate

    'add column to put formula in
    Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Dim LstRwCD As Long
    With ActiveSheet
    LstRwCD = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
      Range("B2:B" & LstRwCD) = "=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,N:N,""Yes"")"
      Range(Range("B2"), Range("B" & LstRwCD)).FillDown
      
    'This forces the formula to calculate
    Worksheets("Total").Columns(2).Calculate
    
'filter if 1 or 2, all with at least one Yes in a pair.
          Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:T").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="2"
        
    Worksheets("Total").Range("A1:T" & LstRwCD).Copy Worksheets("Total Yes").Range("A1")
       
  'delete the columns with the formula  
    Sheets("Total Yes").Range("B:B").EntireColumn.Delete
    Sheets("Total").Range("B:B").EntireColumn.Delete
```